# Laravel pluck value and append additional string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am getting the list of books through pluck

```
$outputArray = $list->pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
```

so I have a list of all possible books. Then through `$books_selected = $books->pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();`
I have a selected books. In my output array I would like to appened True if the id is in $books_selected and false otherwise. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pluck with multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947515/pluck-with-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use [`Collections#map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-map):

```
$outputArray = $list
  ->pluck('title', 'id')
  ->map(function ($title, $id) use ($books_selected) {
    return [$title, in_array($id, $books_selected)];
  });
```

Or in a shorter form if you're using PHP 7.4:

```
$outputArray = $list
  ->pluck('title', 'id')
  ->map(fn($title, $id) => [$title, in_array($id, $books_selected)]);
```

Your final array should be in this form:

```
[
  id1 => ['title1', true],
  id2 => ['title2', false],
  ...
]
```