# Create array in array laravel for coordinate

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

How to create array in array in easiest way

**better if use 1 query and get the output array in array**

This is my query to get coordinates y and x

```
$get_coordinate_y = Location::
          select('middle_point_y')
          ->where('id_loc', $id_loc)
          ->pluck('middle_point_y'); //output: [20,30,55]
$get_coordinate_x = Location::
          select('middle_point_x')
          ->where('id_loc', $id_loc)
          ->pluck('middle_point_x'); //output: [45,50,76]
```

From 2 queries above I've 2 arrays.

How to make simple coordinates like:

```
$coordinates=[
      [20,45],
      [30,50],
      [55,76]
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pluck with multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947515/pluck-with-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map after getting data from DB using eloquent ->

```
$coordinates = Location::
      select('middle_point_y','middle_point_x')
      ->where('id_loc', $id_loc)
      ->get()->map(function($l){
      return [
          $l->middle_point_y,$l->middle_point_x
];
});
```

> output should be => $coordinates=[
> [20,45],
> [30,50],
> [55,76] ]

Comment: perfect! thank you @md rana hossain for the answer.